# Existe alguma forma de diminuir a quantidade de else e if?

Tags: c#, if, estilo-de-codificação, else

Eu deveria criar as condições para cadastro de alunos baseado na idade deles, eu queria saber se existe alguma forma de diminuir a quantidade de `if` nesse trecho do código:

```
int idade = Convert.ToInt32(txtAnoUltimoAniversario.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(txtAnoNascimento.Text);
            if (idade > 17)
            {
                lblCategoria.Text = "Adulto";
            }
            else if (idade < 13)
            {
                lblCategoria.Text = "Juvenil B";
            }
            else if (idade < 10)
            {
                lblCategoria.Text = "Juvenil A";
            }
            else if (idade < 7)
            {
                lblCategoria.Text = "Infantil B";
            }
            else if (idade <= 5)
            {
                lblCategoria.Text = "Infatil A";
            }
            else
            {
                lblCategoria.Text = "Não existe categoria";
            }



        }
```

Comment: Já pensou em usar `switch/case`?

Comment: Não tem erro aí? Porque tem idades no meio que ficam sem ter categoria. Primeiro precisa ter a lógica correta, porque isso pode mudar otimizações.

Comment: tem erro também na lógica, se a idade for 5 entra logo no `if` do `< 13`

Comment: Caro Filipe, não tem haver com o assunto, mas a ordem das ifs com certeza esta errada, qualquer valor menor que 13, mesmo que idade seja `1`, vai sempre cair em `else if (idade < 13)`, pode fazer o teste sentado o valor manualmente, sempre vai ser `Juvenil B`, mesmo que colocasse 5 anos. Veja o teste online da sua IF: https://ideone.com/cMZgoO

Comment: é verdade, a lógica está toda bagunçada, agora que parei para olhar, vou tentar consertar isso primeiro.

Comment: Mesmo que vc possa diminuir a quantidade de `if`s, qual seria o benefício? Provavelmente a maior parte das "soluções" vai ficar pior tecnicamente.

Comment: Caro Filipe, concordo totalmente com o @Bacco , quero dizer, se realmente você tivesse umas 20 `if`s até seria razoavel tentar um `Dictionary` (ou um enumerador), porque realmente teria um problema (já que 20 é um exagero), mas com toda certeza teria uma forma uma ou mais formas **especificas** de resolver (**que vai depender** de cada código, **NÃO** tem solução global mágica), mas encurtar IFs de nada vai ajudar aqui, aliais vai diminuir até a facilidade de leitura, o que deveria se preocupar. Tem gente que pensa em diminuir ifs e criar classes megazords, o que é pior ainda.

Comment: @Filipe.C Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Comment: @Filipe.C Com o C# 9.0, você, pode reduzir os ifs, com o novo formato de switch statements. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression

Answer (score 10):

Até antes da versão 8 em essência não dá (veja abaixo que fica bem melhor na versões mais novas), pelo menos não de uma forma que valha a pena. É possível encurtar o código e é possível consertar um problema quando o dado é digitado errado que não está contemplado aí. Também acho que tem um problema de lógica nesta comparação toda, mas não pode afirmar.

```
if (!int.TryParse(txtAnoUltimoAniversario.Text, out var aniversario) || !int.TryParse(txtAnoNascimento.Text, out var ano) {
    //faz alguma coisa aqui para indicar que os dados foram digitados errados
    //Pode ser que seja dizer que não tem categoria, precisa pensar na UX
}
var idade = aniversario - ano;
if (idade < 6) lblCategoria.Text = "Infatil A";
else if (idade < 7) lblCategoria.Text = "Infantil B";
else if (idade < 10) lblCategoria.Text = "Juvenil A";
else if (idade < 13) lblCategoria.Text = "Juvenil B";
else if (idade > 17) lblCategoria.Text = "Adulto"; //e os que estão entre 13 e 17 não existem?
else lblCategoria.Text = "Não existe categoria";
```

Eu pensei em usar um dicionário, mas eu não ia prejudicar a performance para fazer algo que teria uma quantidade de linhas maior que a solução direta. Se ela tivesse reduzido bastante a quantidade de linhas talvez eu faria, mas não neste caso, inclusive porque pode haver exceções no futuro que o dicionário nem funcione.

O que dá para fazer é encurtar um pouco mais o código colocando uma variável de nome curto com as *strings* e aí atribuí-la na *label*.

Fiz um código ligeiramente diferente para testar:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Compara(20, 15);
        Compara(20, 14);
        Compara(20, 11);
        Compara(20, 8);
        Compara(20, 2);
    }
    private static void Compara(int aniversario, int ano) {
        var idade = aniversario - ano;
        string texto;
        if (idade < 6) texto = "Infatil A";
        else if (idade < 7) texto = "Infantil B";
        else if (idade < 10) texto = "Juvenil A";
        else if (idade < 13) texto = "Juvenil B";
        else if (idade > 17) texto = "Adulto"; //e os que estão entre 13 e 17 não existem?
        else texto = "Não existe categoria";
        WriteLine(texto);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GP49bu). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QXdoiV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/Simplification.cs).

Um `switch` deixaria até maior, mas em C# 8 tem uma sintaxe que pode ser útil usar o [`switch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), com 9 melhor ainda:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Compara(20, 15);
        Compara(20, 14);
        Compara(20, 11);
        Compara(20, 8);
        Compara(20, 2);
    }
    private static void Compara(int aniversario, int ano) => WriteLine((aniversario - ano) switch {
            < 6 => "Infatil A",
            < 7 => "Infantil B",
            < 10 => "Juvenil A",
            < 13 => "Juvenil B",
            > 17 => "Adulto",
            _ =>  "Não existe categoria",
        });
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rwBmGi). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/SwitchAge.cs).

Mais curto e mais eficiente que a opção de dicionário.

Answer (score 10):

Pode usar um [dicionario](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) como alternativa:

```
var idade = 12;

var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 6, "Infatil A" },
    { 7, "Infatil B" },
    { 10, "Juvenil A" },
    { 13, "Juvenil B" },
    { 18, "Não existe categoria" },
    { int.MaxValue, "Adulto" },
};

var result = dic.OrderBy(k => k.Key).FirstOrDefault(e => idade < e.Key).Value;
```